# CiviCRM Member Import Tool Issue

Tags: civimember, import

We are attempting a CiviCRM Member import for a client on CiviCRM 4.6.12.
The import starts to run but then fails saying no memberships were created.

- Nothing is logged to the CiviCRM log file.
- The .csv file detailing the import errors says for ecah line *'DB Constraint Violation - possibly membership_type_id should possibly be marked as mandatory for this API. If so, please raise a bug report'*

The client says there have been no reported upgrade errors and each member record in the Db has a valid membership type ID.

Has anyone had a similar issue?

Oliver

Comment: Ollie - want to be clear. Using Import Wizard, or API (assuming the latter but I assume too often)

Comment: You have already imported the contacts into Civi, yes? The member record in the DB - that's your internal member ID or the CiviMember ID?

Comment: Yes, this is via the import wizard. And when I said member record I meant the internal member ID. Olly

Comment: Civi will create the CiviMember ID automatically. You can't import into that field. You can, however, import the internal member ID into the External ID field when you import Contact. When you import the memberships, match the Internal Member ID to the External Member ID you imported with the contact.